# How to remove Token in SessionStorage after leaving Application in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, url, routes

I want to erase my sessionStorage every time I leave my application.

AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

  constructor(private overlayService: OverlayService, private logger: LoggerService, private userService: UserService, private oAuthStorage: OAuthStorage) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleBeforeUnload);
  }

  handleBeforeUnload = () => {
    this.oAuthStorage.removeItem("access_token")
    this.oAuthStorage.removeItem("refresh_token")
    this.oAuthStorage.removeItem("id_token")
  }

  closeOverlay() {
    this.overlayService.closeOverlayByUrl();
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.userService.isLoggedIn();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleBeforeUnload)
  }
```

How can I now check in handleBeforeUnload, that I for example put another target URL that leaves my application by navigating on another page?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that the targetDomain variable is being accessed outside the NavigationStart event handler, which means it's likely to be undefined when you try to log it to the console or use it in the ngOnDestroy method.

To solve this issue, you can move the code that relies on targetDomain inside the NavigationStart event handler, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      const url = event.url;
      const urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree([url]);
      this.targetUrl = this.router.serializeUrl(urlTree);
      try {
        const parsedUrl = new URL(this.targetUrl);
        console.log(parsedUrl);
        this.targetDomain = parsedUrl.hostname;

        // Check targetDomain here
        if (this.targetDomain !== 'ven10085local') {
          this.oAuthStorage.removeItem("access_token");
          this.oAuthStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
          this.oAuthStorage.removeItem("id_token");
        }

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(('Error parsing URL: ' +  this.targetUrl));
      }
    }
  });

  window.onbeforeunload= () => this.ngOnDestroy();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

This way, targetDomain will be defined and can be used inside the NavigationStart event handler, which is where you should be checking the target domain and clearing the session storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just found out, you can't get the target URL before navigating to it. I reformulated my question